# Import multiple web files in a sequence

Tags: r

I wish to open multiple files from web urls that follow a consistent sequence as follows:

```
file001=read.table("https://...file_001.dat")
file002=read.table("https://...file_002.dat")
file003=read.table("https://...file_003.dat")
```

How can I create a piece of code that opens multiple consecutive web files in a sequence like this?

Comment: ?list.files will help you out!

Comment: does each web file have a common extension?

Comment: Yes, they are webfile_001, webfile_002 etc. as listed above.

Comment: i didn't get it.. is it this way : file1 = "C:\\...\webfile_001.xx") what would be "xx" in your case?

Comment: the file suffix is .dat in these cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path="/path/to/all_webfiles"
x=list.files(path = path, pattern = ".dat")
final_pathname = paste0(path, x)

L=lapply(seq_along(final_pathname), function(i) read.table(final_pathname[i]))
```

---

Post your edits to the question,

```
i <- 1:10 # assuming only 10 files
l <- lapply(seq_along(i), function(j) read.table(paste0("http://file00", j)))
```

here `l` will contain each dataframe provided your weblink is correct and works!

Comment: Does this solution imply I have saved the webfiles to a directory somewhere? I am actually taking the files straight from the web.